# Rename command to delete substring

Tags: text-processing, command-line, perl, rename, batch-jobs

I am trying to batch rename the following files:

```
art-faculty-3_29060055362_o.jpeg  
fine-arts-division-faculty-2016-2017-5_29165851925_o.jpeg  
theatre-faculty-2016-2017-1_29132529356_o.jpeg
art-history-faculty-2016-2017-1_29060057642_o.jpeg         
music-faculty-2016-2017-1_29132523816_o.jpeg
```

I would like to rename them to:

```
art-faculty.jpeg                           
fine-arts-division-faculty.jpeg
theatre-faculty.jpeg
art-history-faculty.jpeg  
music-faculty.jpeg
```

---

Here is what I have so far:

```
rename -n -D '/faculty(.*)/g' -X -v *
```

This returns:

```
Using expression: sub { use feature ':5.18'; s/\/faculty\(\.\*\)\/g//g; s/\.   ([^.]+)\z//x and do { push @EXT, $1; $EXT = join ".", reverse @EXT } }
'art-faculty-3_29060055362_o.jpeg' unchanged
'art-history-faculty-2016-2017-1_29060057642_o.jpeg' unchanged
'fine-arts-division-faculty-2016-2017-5_29165851925_o.jpeg' unchanged
'music-faculty-2016-2017-1_29132523816_o.jpeg' unchanged
'theatre-faculty-2016-2017-1_29132529356_o.jpeg' unchanged
```

**Is it possible to use REGEX with the delete (-D) transformation?** If so, how would I use it to make the transformation I show above? If not, please point me in the right direction for performing transformations with `rename` using REGEX.

[image: A quick reference]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in *.jpeg; do echo mv "$i" "${i%faculty*}faculty.jpeg" ; done
```

if okay as per requirements, remove `echo` to change the file names

---

The perl rename command on my system has only the options `-v -f -n`

```
$ rename -n 's/faculty\K.*(?=\.jpeg)//' *.jpeg
art-faculty-3_29060055362_o.jpeg renamed as art-faculty.jpeg
art-history-faculty-2016-2017-1_29060057642_o.jpeg renamed as art-history-faculty.jpeg
fine-arts-division-faculty-2016-2017-5_29165851925_o.jpeg renamed as fine-arts-division-faculty.jpeg
music-faculty-2016-2017-1_29132523816_o.jpeg renamed as music-faculty.jpeg
theatre-faculty-2016-2017-1_29132529356_o.jpeg renamed as theatre-faculty.jpeg
```